Free interactive map API or tool for WPF program
I have a database with some information (no more than a few sentences) on each county in a few states. What I am trying to make is a very simple program that allows the user to hover or click on each county in an interactive map, and have the county specific information pop up. My question about this is, is there a free API or package of some kind that would allow me to create or use a simple filled map this way?
I looked into Bing Maps, Azure Maps and ArcGIS but all of them seemed to have a pay wall after a transaction threshold was met. For ArcGIS there is a free public account for non-commercial projects, which this would be, but this would also be a private project with sensitive data. Is that allowed with a public account? Is there a better option? At most this project would be used by a hundred or so individuals a few times a day.

If it's only "a hundred or so individuals a few times a day", you should be able to use the OpenStreetMap ecosystem.  Specifically, you're likely to want to use Leaflet in a web control for your user interface, and some combination of Nominatim and Overpass for getting county outlines.
You may want to embed the outline data into your program rather than downloading it on demand, to avoid the risk of being rate-limited by Nominatim or your chosen Overpass provider.

Leaflet is what I am currently using and it is so far working as intended. Thank you for the rate limitation tip, much appreciated!
